# Block incoming/outgoing SMS on Android

Tags: android, sms, block

Does anyone know a reliable way to block incoming/outgoing SMS messages through code? It's ok if the actual SMS messages are being received, but I would like to block any notifications of that SMS being received. Also, the user shouldn't be allowed to send (or prefferably even type) an SMS message. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Check again. This is driving me nuts. I have made the progress of blocking incoming SMS notifications through a BroadcastReceiver, but blocking outgoing SMS is driving me crazy... Ideally, I would'nt even want the user to open the Messaging app. Is there a way to kill an external process (i.e. the Messaging app)? I have tried it through restartPackage, but that terminates my app unexpectedly. I assume that is because of a permissions/security problem? Oh, and for people wondering why I need to do this, it's because I need to create an app similar to Textecution (www.textecution.com). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can't block outgoing text messages.

Here's what I use for blocking incoming texts.

---

SmsReceiver.java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SEND_SMS";
public static int MSG_TPE=0;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{ 
    String MSG_TYPE=intent.getAction();
        if(MSG_TYPE.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
    {
//          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SMS Received: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//          toast.show();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
    for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) 
    {
        smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
    }

    // show first message
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"BLOCKED Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
        abortBroadcast();
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Blocking SMS **********************");
        }

    }
    else if(MSG_TYPE.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SEND_SMS"))
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SMS SENT: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        abortBroadcast();
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Blocking SMS **********************");
        }

    }
    else
    {

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,"SIN ELSE: "+MSG_TYPE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
        abortBroadcast();
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Blocking SMS **********************");
        }

    }

}

}
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="APP.PACKAGE.NAMEHERE"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<supports-screens 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".APPACTIVITYHERE"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >


    <service android:name=".MyService" android:enabled="true"/>
     <receiver android:name="SmsReceiver">
      <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_SENT"/>
      </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

     <service android:name=".MyServiceSentReceived" android:enabled="true"/>
      <receiver android:name="SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483645">
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

</application>
```

The main thing to take away from the manifest is the service block, receiver block, and the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding blocking of incoming sms. You can register broadcast receiver with high priority so your code gets called before system app is called. Than in broadcast receiver, you can abort the broadcast and other apps won't see it.

register receiver in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and then in broadcast receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

Comment: @Vishnu Mohan G: highest priority is 1000, register a receiver with 1000 priority. Then in onReceive method, this.abortBroadcast() will abort the broadcast.

Comment: Android Document say "The value must be an integer, such as "100". Higher numbers have a higher priority. The default value is 0. The value must be greater than -1000 and less than 1000", so it must be 999 as per the statement. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html